# Group/filter sub-arrays of a multidimensional array in Ruby/RoR

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, ruby-on-rails-5, filtering

I have a Ruby on Rails query ending by a `.pluck(:id, :title)` and giving me an array full of 2-dimensions arrays like so :

```
array = [[11145, "string1"], [11223, "string1"], [11205, "string2"], [11127, "string2"], [11080, "string3"], [11158, "string3"]]
```

I'd like to group the IDs by title in order to get this result:

```
 [[[11145, 11223], "string1"], [[11205, 11127], "string2"], [[11080, 11158], "string3"]]
```

I've tried to concatenate the IDs directly in the SQL query or manipulate the array but didn't manage my expected result.

Any help is more than welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add what you was tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast solution:

```rb
array.group_by(&:last).transform_values { |e| e.map(&:first) }.to_a
```

1. [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by)
2. [`Hash#transform_values`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values)

One more variant is:

```rb
array.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |obj, res|
  res[obj.last] << obj.first
end.to_a
```

1. [`Hash#default_proc`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc)
2. [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)

**UPD**
I don't know how your query looks like, but if you work with PG, you can try to play with this ending of:

`.group(:title).select('array_agg(id) as ids, title').map { |e| [e.title, e.ids] }`

Comment: Many thanks! Your 3 options work perfectly! I wouldn't have been able to mix these methods to get the result, too deep for me :)

Comment: I believe `.to_a` in the first line is redundant. I don't know if "a bit more optimized" is any better than the first solution (just different). Also, optimized doesn't give quite the desired return value (ordering is different).

Comment: @CarySwoveland emm, nope, without `.to_a` it will return `Hash`. You are right, I have rechecked it with the benchmark, and yeah, looks like it both variants will take +- the same time. Thank you!